# Jquery, Insert an <li> tag at the beginning and remove the last tag keeping only 3 li tags at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using socket.io and twitter streaming API.

Now I have to keep the recent three tweets in a list

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

My Question is how to do this in Jquery? Whenever there is a new tweet I want to insert it in to first li and move the first li tweet in to second li and so on and remove the 4th tweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `.prepend` to insert new element at the beginning of the target element.
- Use `:gt()` to remove the element if length is greater than expected
  `length`.

```js
var count = 0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var li = '<li>Data New' + count + '</li>';
  ++count;
  $('ul').prepend(li);
  if ($('ul li').length > 3) {
    $('ul li:gt(2)').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Data</li>
  <li>Data</li>
  <li>Data</li>
</ul>
<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: @JagadeshaNH, Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prepend()` method in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). This adds HTML element as the first node of the target.

```
$("ul").prepend("<li>new item</li>");
```

And as @Kartikeya suggested, remove the last one like:

```
$("ul > li:last").remove();
```

Comment: and `$('ul > li:last').remove()` or `$('ul > li').last().remove()` as OP wants latest three tweets at a time.